# Narrow convergence and convergence of points

Tags: probability, measure-theory, weak-convergence, semi-riemannian-geometry

I'm reading a paper about the curvature-dimension condition in Lorentzian geodesic spaces, and there's this line:
"Let $\mathfrak{m}_j\rightharpoonup\mathfrak{m}_\infty$ be probability measures converging narrowly (the ambient space is a proper metric space). Then from that we deduce the existence of a sequence $x_j\in\mathrm{supp}\,\mathfrak{m}_j$ with $x_j\rightarrow x_\infty\in\mathrm{supp}\,\mathfrak{m}_\infty$." Does this come from the convergence of the measures (that implies some sort of convergence of the supports?)?

Comment: Does narrow convergence mean "weak convergence" in the sense that $\int f \,dm_j\rightarrow{j\rightarrow\infty}\int f\,dm$ for all $f$ bounded and continuous?

Comment: Take $x\in\operatorname{sump}(m)$. Then for any $r>0$, $m(B(x;r)>0$. By the Portmanteau theorem $\limsup_n m_n(B(x;r))\geq m(B(x;r))>0$. that may help you contract sequence with $x_k$ in the support os some $m_{n_k}$ and $x_k$ converging to $x$.

Comment: Thank you! (Yes narrow convergence is the one you said. For probability measures it's equivalent to the weak* one)